# If I delete a video from my computer after I've imported it, will it delete from the video I'm editing?

Tags: vegas-pro

If I delete a video from my computer after I've imported it, will it delete from the video I'm editing?

I've imported many video clips into a video project I'm currently working on (I'm using Vegas Pro 16). But I want to help clear up some space on my computer, so if I deleted those clips from their original location, would they still remain for me to work with in Vegas?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [video.se]!  **:-)** As you're new here: Please don't mark your question as [solved] but click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer that solved your issue, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

According to the on-line [manual](http://dl03.vegascreativesoftware.com/manual_vp16_en.pdf) page 57 of this commercial software this is only true if you:

1. have selected the <kbd>Copy media with project</kbd> checkbox and
2. Clicked the <kbd>Save</kbd> button

### for all your projects!

If you forgot to do that with just one, the answer is:

> No, deleting the original file *will delete* it from all of the projects where you did not click that option.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike some other editing tools, Vegas does not convert imported video into its own intermediate format, but works directly with what you have. Importing means Vegas knows about these clips and has built quick-access metadata about them.

Any editing you do is non-destructive as all editing operations are stored in Vegas's own files as a series of commands, but it needs source videos to which it applies these commands.

TLDR: If you delete the source files your Vegas timeline will effectively be destroyed. Of course, videos that you've rendered will remain intact.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I am sorry I was not completely clear. The rendered video will, of course, remain intact if the source clips are deleted. I was talking about the project and the timeline - it uses source clips and will be destroyed when the source clips are destroyed. Sorry for confusion. I will edit my reply accordingly.

Comment: Oh, now it makes perfect sense, no problem there, great! I deleted my panicked comment.